# How to get media queries/css working in html email

Tags: html, css, gmail, media-queries

I'm having an issue with getting an html email to display correctly. The html contains media queries to make it responsive to different sized devices... it displays correctly in the browser but when sent as an email, the css doesn't seem to be working properly to adjust the icon positions.

I've tried minifying the css, making the css !important, etc and nothing has worked. Upon inspection of the email's html in Gmail, I noticed that the class names had been changed by Google and none of the rules were applied. Not sure why this is happening or how to get around it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Testing Testing 123</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            #bodyBg {
                margin: 0px;
                padding: 0px;
                background-color: white;
            }


            @media only screen 
            and (max-device-width: 325px)
            and (min-device-height: 500px)
            and (max-device-height: 580px){
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:62px; 
                    width: 66px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 150px;
                    width:100%
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 550px; 
                    width: 90%;
                    left: -8px;
                    margin-left:auto; 
                    margin-right:auto;                    
                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height: 79.36px; 
                    width: 84.48px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }


            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 326px)
            and (max-device-width: 364px) {
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:62px; 
                    width: 66px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 150px;
                    width:100%
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 550px; 
                    width: 90%;
                    left: -8px;
                    margin-left:auto; 
                    margin-right:auto;                    
                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height: 79.36px; 
                    width: 84.48px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }


            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 365px)
            and (max-device-width: 499px)
            and (max-device-height: 700px){
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:62px; 
                    width: 66px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 150px; 
                    width:100%
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 550px; 
                    width: 100%;
                    left: -8px;

                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height: 79.36px; 
                    width: 84.48px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }


            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 365px)
            and (max-device-width: 499px)
            and (min-device-height: 701px){
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:124px; 
                    width: 132px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 160px; 
                    width:100%
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 850px; 
                    width: 100%;
                    left: -8px;

                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height:124px; 
                    width: 132px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }

            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 400px)
            and (max-device-width: 450px)
            and (min-device-height: 790px)
            and (max-device-height: 850px){
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:248px; 
                    width: 264px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 300px; 
                    width:100%
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 1620px; 
                    width: 90%;
                    left: -8px;
                    margin-left:auto; 
                    margin-right:auto;                    
                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height: 248px; 
                    width: 264px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }



            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 400px)
            and (max-device-width: 450px)
            and (min-device-height: 700px)
            and (max-device-height: 780px){                
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height: 75.39px; 
                    width: 80.256px; 
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 165px; 
                    width:100%                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 590px; 
                    width: 90%;
                    left: -8px;
                    margin-left:auto; 
                    margin-right:auto;                    
                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height: 79.36px; 
                    width: 84.48px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }



            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 700px)
            and (max-device-width: 900px) {
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:111.6px; 
                    width: 118.8px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 170px; 
                    width: 70%;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 705px; 
                    width: 40%;
                    left: -8px;

                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height:99.2px; 
                    width: 105.6px; 
                }
                socialCells {
                    padding-right: 5px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }

            @media only screen 
            and (min-device-width: 901px) {
                .helpfulIcons {
                    height:173.6px; 
                    width: 184.8px;
                }
                #helpfulIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 230px; 
                    width: 90%;
                    margin-left: auto;
                    margin-right: auto;
                }
                #socialIconTable {
                    position: relative; 
                    bottom: 930px; 
                    width: 40%;

                }
                .socialIcons {
                    height: 124px; 
                    width: 132px; 
                }
                .socialCells {
                    padding-right: 10px; 
                    width:25%; 
                    text-align: center;
                }
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body id="bodyBg">
        <!--[if gte MSO 9]>
        <table width="411"><tr><td>
        <![endif]-->
        <table id="bgTable" style="width:100%">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <img src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/bg_411x823.jpg" alt="king tax get social" style="width:100%" />
                    <table id="helpfulIconTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-left: 20px; padding-right: 20px; width:33.33%; text-align: center;"><a href="https://sa.www4.irs.gov/irfof/lang/en/irfofgetstatus.jsp" target="_blank"><img alt="IRS Where's My Refund" class="helpfulIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/irs_icon.png" /></a></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 20px; width:33.33%; text-align: center;"><a href="https://dor.georgia.gov/wheres-my-refund" target="_blank"><img alt="GA Where's My Refund" class="helpfulIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/ga_icon.png" /></a></td>
                            <td style="padding-right: 20px; width:33.33%; text-align: center;"><a href="https://mydorway.dor.sc.gov/_/" target="_blank"><img alt="SC Where's My Refund" class="helpfulIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/sc_icon.png" /></a></td>
                        </tr>                        
                    </table>
                    <table id="socialIconTable">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="socialCells" style="padding-left: 20px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/kingtaxsavannah" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" class="socialIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/facebook.png" /></a></td>
                            <td class="socialCells"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/kingtaxsavannah" target="_blank"><img alt="Instagram" class="socialIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/instagram.png" /></a></td>
                            <td class="socialCells"><a href="https://twitter.com/KingTaxSavannah" target="_blank"><img alt="Twitter" class="socialIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/linkedin.png" /></a></td>
                            <td class="socialCells"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/kingtaxsavannah" target="_blank"><img alt="Linkedin" class="socialIcons" src="http://kingtaxsavannah.com/tax-prep/images/phone/icons/twitter.png" /></a></td>                            
                        </tr>                        
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if gte MSO 9]>
        </td></tr></table>
        <![endif]-->
    </body>
</html>
```

When I open the html file in chrome and test it under different mobile device settings, the icons display in the exact location where I'd like for them to be. But when I actually send the html as an email, all of the icons are beneath the main image.

Comment: gmail does not support the position property, emails are always a pain best to keep it as simple as possible. https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comment. I thought Gmail wasn't honoring any of my css but it turns out, like you said, they just don't allow positioning. So I made my background image the background-image of a table and placed the icons inside of individual cells of a table row. I'm using empty table rows for positioning. The css adjusts the height of the empty table rows based upon the size of the device's screen via media queries. Works like a charm! Thanks!